# Matplotlib in python on a mac opens a new window

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am new to the world of mac. In python we I want to visualize a data, I use matplotlib's pyplot to generate a plot but when I do pyplot.show() it creates a new window. This behavior also happens inside my ipython notebook too - see image below. I wanted it to embed the image inside the notebook.

How can I correct this ?

[image: This is what it looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ipython notebook --pylab inline` when you launch ipython.

Comment: I'm also running python in pydev inside eclipse. How can I generate plots that show up inside eclipse instead of a separate window ?

Answer (score 0):

Input in a cell, the cell magic `%pylab inline` or `%matplotlib inline` will make the plots appear inline/interactive (instead of a new window).

Not that if you use `%matplotlib` cell magic, you still need `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `import numpy as np` etc. With `%pylab` cell magic you don't.